# Socketing C++ to PHP or Android

Tags: php, android, c++, sockets

I have code for client - server. Server code use C++ with local port and the client i wanna make use PHP or Android. But I dont't know how to make the code.

NB :

1. Server App use local port 10001

My code server like this (networkex.cpp)

```
bool CNetworkEX::LoginStatRequest(int n, char* pMsg)
{
_login_server_stat_request_aclo* pRecv = (_login_server_stat_request_aclo*)pMsg;

_login_server_stat_result_loac Send;
Send.wClientIndex = pRecv->wClientIndex;

if ( pRecv->byStat == 0 )
{

}
else if ( pRecv->byStat == 1 )
{
    g_Main.m_bExternalOpen = true;
    ::StringOutput("Connection External Open");
}
else if ( pRecv->byStat == 2 )
{
    g_Main.m_bExternalOpen = false;
    ::StringOutput("Connection External Close");
}

if ( g_Main.m_bExternalOpen )
    Send.byRet = 1;
else
    Send.byRet = 2;

BYTE byType[msg_header_num] = {system_msg, login_server_stat_result_loac};
m_pProcess[LINE_ACCOUNT]->LoadSendMsg(0, byType, (char*)&Send, Send.size());

return true;
}
```

My main (mainthread.cpp)

```
bool CMainThread::CommandProcess(char* pszCmd)
{
int nWordNum = ::ParsingCommand(pszCmd, max_cheat_word, s_pszDstCheat, max_cheat_word_size);
if(nWordNum <= 0)
    return false;

if(!strcmp("/open", s_pszDstCheat[0]))
{
    ::StringOutput("Connection External Open"); 
    m_bExternalOpen = true;
    return true;
}
else if(!strcmp("/close", s_pszDstCheat[0]))
{
    ::StringOutput("Connection External Close");    
    m_bExternalOpen = false;
    return true;
}
else if(!strcmp("/patchup", s_pszDstCheat[0]))
{
    DWORD dwBufNum = m_dwPatchServerNum + 1;
    if(dwBufNum > MAX_PATCHER_PER_GLOBAL)
        dwBufNum = MAX_PATCHER_PER_GLOBAL;      

    ::StringOutput("Patch Server increases(%d -> %d)", m_dwPatchServerNum, dwBufNum);   
    m_dwPatchServerNum = dwBufNum;
    return true;
}
else if(!strcmp("/patchdown", s_pszDstCheat[0]))
{
    DWORD dwBufNum;
    if(m_dwPatchServerNum <= 1)
        dwBufNum = 1;
    else
        dwBufNum = m_dwPatchServerNum - 1;  

    ::StringOutput("Patch Server decreases(%d -> %d)", m_dwPatchServerNum, dwBufNum);   
    m_dwPatchServerNum = dwBufNum;
    return true;
}
else if(!strcmp("/예약", s_pszDstCheat[0]))
{
    if(nWordNum > 1)
    {
        if(!strcmp("The outer block", s_pszDstCheat[1]) && nWordNum == 7)
        {
            if(_SetReserveExternalClose(atoi(s_pszDstCheat[2]), atoi(s_pszDstCheat[3]), atoi(s_pszDstCheat[4]), atoi(s_pszDstCheat[5]), atoi(s_pszDstCheat[6])))
                ::StringOutput("Reservations accepted");
            else
                ::StringOutput("Booking time errors");
            return true;
        }
    }
}
else if(!strcmp("/loginstat", s_pszDstCheat[0]))
{
    if ( m_bExternalOpen )
        ::StringOutput("External access status");
    else
        ::StringOutput("External connection error status");
    return true;
}
else if(!strcmp("/clientcount", s_pszDstCheat[0]))
{
    DWORD dwClientCount = CountAliveConnection();
    ::StringOutput( "Connection : %d", dwClientCount );
    return true;
}

return false;
}
```

I wanna my client just send the message like "/open" or "close" but i don't know hot to write the code in php or android. anyone can help me to solve my problem?

Edit

I already try use this php code

```
<?php
$host    = "127.0.0.1";
$port    = 10001;
$message = "open";
echo "Message To server :".$message;
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
// send string to server
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
// get server response
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
// close socket
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

and the respon in my browser like this http://prntscr.com/dqje54 and in my server app not recieve the message /open

Comment: You better google for android client server example. You will find ready java code soon.

Comment: if I use php is possible?

Comment: You can find ready server code for php too i think. But do you have such a domain?

Comment: domain? for what? I just try in local sir ... with ip 127.0.0.1 or localhost

Comment: Ok. On a local pc. You know how to install php server code there? If your client runs on an android device you cannot use 127.0.0.1 or localhost to connect.

Comment: i know how to connect android to php ... I just don't know how to send word to c++ use socket sir